# После Transform scale высота родителя остаётся

Tags: html, css

Есть ребёнок и родитель, у ребёнка размеры 1610x900, у родителя высота примерно 300px. Добавил ребёнка в родителя, transform:scale(0.345), и высота родителя осталось 1147.97px. Те, как до трансформации. Из-за этого отодвигает ниже лежащий блок. max-height не вариант, нужно что-бы блоки прилегали вплотную, а если высота у телефона, например, меньше чем max-height нижний блок уходит в никуда.

```
Пример:
```

```css
.child
{
 width:600px;
 height:600px;
 background-color:blue;
}
.parent
{
 width:100%;
 background-color:green;
}
.row
{
 width:100%;
 height:200px;
 background-color:purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child" style="transform:scale(0.345);"></div>
</div>
<div class="row"></div>
```

Видно, как зелёный блок продолжает идти вниз, хотя синий блок стал меньше после scale().

Есть предположения как фиксить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.child {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: blue;
  transform: scale(0.345);
  transform-origin: top center;
  margin-bottom: -393px;
}

.parent {
  background-color: green;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.row {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="row"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Да, margin-bottom помог.

Comment: Если проблема решена, прими ответ нажатием на галочку слева от него.